# Focus TextBox when TabControl selection changed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have following Problem:

I have two tabs in my TabControl and if the second Tab "TabControl1_Products" is selected I want to set the focus in the "Products_TextBox2" TextBox. 
I wrote this code, which in theory should work, but it somehow does not...

```
private void TabControl1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TabControl1_Products.IsSelected)
    {
        this.Products_TextBox2.Focus();
    }
}
```

I checked, that the Program enters the if query, but it does not change the focus to the TextBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Dispatcher:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,new Action(() => thi.Products_TextBox2.Focus()));
```

Comment: Thanks that is working now! Could you explain, WHY this is working and my version wasnt?

Comment: I am not sure, if i can explain it correctly: The UI is running on one thread and was not fully loaded when Focus() was called, so the Focus()-Call was disregarded. With the Dispatcher you spin off a new thread wich will run in the Background as soon as the main UI-Thread is finished loading.

Comment: I thought it would be something like this, thank you for explaining!